# Not able to call an argument using findstr command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch file that will search for a string in a LOG file. The string contains two static and two dynamic part. The dynamic part is what we enter at runtime. I concatenating the static and dynamic part in the batch script itself and searching for it in the file.

For example, if the static string is "hello world | " and " | "

the dynamic strings are "2013" and "2014", my final string is like

finalstring= hello world | 2013 | 2014

And to eliminate the double quotes, i'm using delayed expansion. Here's my code below:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
echo %mydate%


setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !str!


setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "str2=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !str2!



setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "string1=hello world | "
set "string1=%~string1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !string1!


setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "pipesign= | "
set "pipesign=%~pipesign"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo !pipesign!


:concat 
set "finalstring=%string1%%str%"
set "finalstring2=%finalstring%%pipesign%"
set "finalstring3=%finalstring2%%str2%"

echo %finalstring3%
:concat

findstr %finalstring3% C:\test\log20132502
```

The output of my batch file is as follows:

```
2013-02-25
2013
2014
'2013' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batchfile
```

My assumption is that there is an error which concatenating the string and that the argument is not properly called in the "finalstring"

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you remove the "echo off" command it will probably be more obvious what is going wrong.  I think the problem is that you need to put the search string in quotes, something like: `findstr /c:"%finalstring3%" c:\test\log20132502`

Answer (score 0):

There are times when you must toggle delayed expansion on and off, but you really should try to structure your code to minimize the number of times. You have gone overboard in your code.

You cannot use `%~var` to remove enclosing quotes from a variable value. That only works for parameters, as in `%~1`, or FOR variables, as in `%%~A`. The way you have written your code, there is no need to remove quotes. `set "var=value"` has quotes to protect the value during the assignment, but the quotes are not included in the value.

Your error message stems from the fact that the pipe must be quoted (or escaped) within your FINDSTR line.

FINDSTR will split the search string into multiple search strings, delimited by spaces. You want to inclide space within the search string, so you need the FINDSTR `/C:"search string"` option.

I don't understand the purpose of your date processing at the top, but I prerserved it.

Presumably, `2013` and `2014` are passed in as parameters `%1` and `%2`.

I believe your code can be simplified as below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
echo %mydate%

set "mySearch=hello world | %~1 | %~2"
echo !mySearch!

findstr /c:"!mySearch!" c:\test\log20132502
```

If the value of `%1` or `%2` could ever contain `!`, then the delayed expansion will corrupt the value during the assignment of `mySearch`. Toggling delayed expansion can help in that case.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
echo %mydate%

set "mySearch=hello world | %~1 | %~2"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo !mySearch!
endlocal

findstr /c:"!mySearch!" c:\test\log20132502
```

But I suspect that the printout of the search string is just for debugging purposes. If you don't really need the variable or the printout of the search string, then your code can simply become

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
echo %mydate%

findstr /c:"hello world | %~1 | %~2" c:\test\log20132502
```